# Matrix Transformation Problem

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

> The transformation matrix $P$ represents a $90^\circ$ anticlockwise
> rotation about the origin.
>
> Describe fully the single transformation represented by the matrix
> $P^3$

From my working, $P$ would equate to

\begin{equation*}
P = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Now to find the transformation shown by $P^3$, would I have to cube the matrix or is there something that I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute $P^3$ or use the fact that if $P$ rotates vectors through an angle $\theta$, then $P^n$ rotates vectors through the angle $n\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

$P^3$ means applying transformation $P$ three times, so its result is  270 degree anticlockwise rotation about the origin.